# HtmlPurifier repeats links

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I'm using HTMLPurifier with my system and for some reason it converts something like this:

```
<div class="item-horizontal mrb14" id="traditional">
<a href="/" title="Traditional">
<h3>Traditional</h3>
</a>
</div>
```

into something like this:

```
<div class="item-horizontal mrb14" id="anchor-traditional">
    <a href="/" title="Traditional"></a>
    <h3><a href="/" title="Traditional">Traditional</a></h3>
    <a href="/" title="Traditional"></a>
</div>
```

Any idea what should I add to the configuration? - my current set up is:

```
require_once('HTMLPurifier.auto.php');
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional');
$config->set('Attr.AllowedFrameTargets', array('_blank'));
$config->set('HTML.Trusted', true);
$config->set('HTML.SafeObject', true);
$config->set('Output.FlashCompat', true);
$config->set('Filter.Custom',  array( new HTMLPurifier_Filter_SafeIframe() ));
$config->set('Attr.EnableID', true);
$config->set('Attr.IDPrefix', 'anchor-');
$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->addAttribute('a', 'href*', 'URI');
$def->addAttribute('a', 'rel', 'CDATA');
$objPurifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
return $objPurifier->purify($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting a block element the `h3` in an `anchor (a)` tag which is an inline lement. If you´re using html5 that is perfectly fine but with xhtml 1.0 as your doctype it´s not.

Here´s an example at [html5doctor](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/).

**Edit**: A bit of googling led me to this post which underlines my [suspicion](http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,5643)

Comment: I'm using html5 - but htmlpurifier doesn't seem to support html5 yet therefore XHTML 1.0 Transitional seem to be one of possibilities I can use when setting the doctype.

Comment: I just found this somehow related [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566301/htmlpurifier-with-an-html5-doctype). So I guess you have to restructure the code. But I´ve actually never used HtmlPurifier, so I might be wrong.

EDIT: I´m sorry the link to the post is kind of old so please just ignore it.

Comment: I meant the post i linked to in my comment not you´re question. Sorry for the confusion.